# Not understanding my __str__ doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python

I am new to classes in Python and I am making a text based version of Blackjack to get more familiar with them. The biggest issue I am facing is getting the `__str__` method to work as expected. Some of the time it works fine (In the `Deck` class shown below), but other times it does not and returns the object type (The `PlayerHand` class shown below). I have tried different formatting styles and converted what I want to print out to string as well with no avail.

```
import random

card_suits = ['Hearts','Spades','Clubs','Diamonds']

card_names = ['Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight',
              'Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King']
```

---

```
class Deck:
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def shuffled_deck(self):
        #Make new Deck and shuffle when class instance is called
        initial_deck = []
        for suit in card_suits:
            for name in card_names:
                initial_deck.append(Card(name,suit))
                random.shuffle(initial_deck)
        self.initial_deck = initial_deck
    
    def remove_card(self):
        removed = []
        removed = self.initial_deck.pop()
        self.removed = removed
        return self.removed
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.removed)
```

---

```
class PlayerHand(Deck):
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    #Deal cards
    def p1(self):
        p1_hand = []
        for card in [0,1]:
            p1_hand.append(Deck.remove_card(self))
            self.p1_hand = p1_hand
        return self.p1_hand
    
    
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.p1_hand[0])
```

---

```
Current_Hand = PlayerHand()
Current_Hand.shuffled_deck()
Current_Hand.p1()
print(PlayerHand)
```

Outputs:

```
<class '__main__.PlayerHand'>
```

Comment: That should be `print(Current_Hand)`. `PlayerHand` is a class

Comment: It's a good practice to use CamelCalse for class names and snake_case for variables and functions. In that way it would be more obvious you're calling print on the class and not the instance. [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Comment: Something weird is going on there imho. If you don't remove before printing you will get AttributeError, because none of those classes initializes `removed` in init, which is bad and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Gameplay I don't understand what you mean. I made the remove method in the Deck Class which was inherited by the PlayerHand Class, and then call this method to ensure cards are removed from the deck whenever a player draws. So no attribute error will arise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to display the class itself, not an instance of it, you should directly print `Current_Hand`, because this variable is an instance.

```py
# your code ...

Current_Hand = PlayerHand()
Current_Hand.shuffled_deck()
Current_Hand.p1()
print(Current_Hand)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with the way this has been written.

```
Firstly, there is no need for inheritance (subclassing).
The deck should be shuffled upon construction.
Each instance of a Player class should be using the same deck.
Cards have values - you should account for that.
A hand may have multiple values if Ace is considered to have a value of 1 or 11.
```

For example:

```
from random import shuffle
from typing import Self

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'


class Deck:
    SUITS = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
    RANKS = ['Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight',
         'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]


    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit, rank, value) for (rank, value) in zip(Deck.RANKS, Deck.VALUES) for suit in Deck.SUITS]
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return '\n'.join(str(card) for card in self.cards)

    def draw(self) -> Card:
        assert len(self.cards) > 0
        return self.cards.pop()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.deck = deck
        self.hand = []

    def deal(self, n: int=1) -> Self:
        self.hand += [self.deck.draw() for _ in range(n)]
        return self

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.hand:
            return ', '.join(str(card) for card in self.hand)
        return 'Empty hand'
    
    def value(self) -> tuple[int, ...]:
        _min, _max = 0, 0
        for card in self.hand:
            _min += card.value
            _max += card.value
            if card.value == 1: # Ace
                _max += 10
        return (_min,) if _min == _max else (_min, _max)


deck = Deck()

player_1 = Player(deck).deal(2)
player_2 = Player(deck).deal(2)

print(player_1, player_1.value())
print(player_2, player_2.value())

for _ in range(2):
    player_1.deal()
    print(player_1, player_1.value())
    player_2.deal()
    print(player_2, player_2.value())
```

**Output (example because it's random):**

```
Eight of Hearts, Five of Diamonds (13,)
Six of Hearts, Three of Diamonds (9,)
Eight of Hearts, Five of Diamonds, Seven of Diamonds (20,)
Six of Hearts, Three of Diamonds, Ten of Hearts (19,)
Eight of Hearts, Five of Diamonds, Seven of Diamonds, Three of Hearts (23,)
Six of Hearts, Three of Diamonds, Ten of Hearts, Ace of Clubs (20, 30)
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: inside `Deck.__init__()`, you can directly create `self.cards` from a nested list comprehension: `self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for rank in RANKS for suit in SUITS]`

Comment: Even more minor quibble: for better encapsulation, `SUITS` and `RANKS` should be class members of Deck, not globals. Then we could have say a Deck stripped of 2s-7s. To support that, suits and ranks could be parameters to `Deck.__init__()` with default values we can override.

Comment: @DarkKnight I intentionally didn't include the card values in my question as I felt it was not needed to understand my issue. Also, I do have a method in Deck that shuffles the deck each time the class is called, and I was planning to call this at the beginning of a game or when the current deck is empty.